# Disnake - Can a bot invoke a slash command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a simple game in disnake that posts a message to a channel when played. At the end of that message, I want to add a "Play again" button. The game is initially started by a slash command. When the "Play again" button is clicked, I would like the bot to invoke the slash command that starts the game again. Is this possible?

In discord.py invoking a regular command was as simple as:

```
await ctx.invoke(self.bot.get_command('my_command'))
```

However, the MessageInteraction object doesn't have an "invoke" method i.e the following doesn't work:

```
await interaction.invoke(self.bot.get_command('my_slash_command'))
```

Edit: I guess the obvious workaround would be to pack the whole game into a function and then call the same function in both the slash command and the button callback (in order to not repeat the code). Is this actually a better way of achieving this? Should interaction processing, in general, always be encapsulated in functions?

Comment: My only thought for you is to just make the code that makes the game run initially, into a function declaration and call it recursively.

Comment: yes thank you, I was just adding this in an edit as I had a similar thought. I guess this would make sense in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

All `ctx.invoke` does is call the command's function as if it were a regular function. For example, `await ctx.invoke(self.bot.get_command("my_command"))` is practically the same as my `await my_command(ctx)` (if the command is defined with its callback being a function with the same name and the function is in scope).

Thus, we can do the same thing with the interaction and `bot.get_slash_command`.

### Code

```py
@bot.slash_command(description="print button")
async def print_button(interaction):
    await interaction.send("gaming", components=[disnake.ui.Button(label="Play again")])
    await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: (i.component and i.component.label == "Play again"))
    await bot.get_slash_command("print_button").callback(interaction)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. For subcommands, I had to separate the slash-command name from the sub-command name by a space in `get_slash_command`, as stated in the docs https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#disnake.ext.commands.Bot.get_slash_command